# Prove: a closed ball is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $Prove: \overline{B(a,r)}$ is a closed set.

We will prove that $\overline{B(a,r)}^{c}$ is an open set.

let there be $x\in\overline{B(a,r)}^{c}\rightarrow ||x-a|>r\rightarrow \exists \delta>0: ||x-a||>r+\delta$

How from here I can conclude that there is an open ball contained in $\overline{B(a,r)}^{c}$ and to finish the proof?

Comment: Might be easier to show that any converging sequence in the closed ball has a limit in the ball. You can use the continuity of the metric for that.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661759/a-closed-ball-in-a-metric-space-is-a-closed-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x \notin \overline {B(a;r)}$. Then, $||x-a|| > r$, so let $||x-a||-r = \epsilon > 0$.

Let's consider $y \in B(x;\frac{\epsilon}2)$. Note that:
\begin{split}
& \implies ||y-a|| \geq ||x-a||-||y-x||  \qquad \text{ (Modified Triangle inequality)}\\
& \implies ||y-a|| \geq r + \epsilon - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \geq r + \frac \epsilon 2 \qquad (\because ||x-a||= r+ \epsilon,||y-x||<\frac \epsilon 2)\\
& \implies ||y-a|| >r\\
& \implies y \notin \overline{B(a;r)}
\end{split}

Hence, the open ball $B(x;\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ is a subset of $\overline{B(a;r)}^c$. This shows that $\overline{B(a;r)}^c$ is open, hence $\overline{B(a;r)}$ is closed.

Comment: $||y-a|| \geq ||x-a||-||y-x||$ can be writing as $||y-a|| \geq ||x-a||-||x-y||$? right?

Comment: @gbox  Yes, because $||x-y|| = ||(-1)(y-x)|| = |(-1)| \cdot ||y-x|| = ||y-x||$, so nothing changes.

Comment: "Let's consider $y \in B(x;\frac{\epsilon}2)$" should be $y \in B(a;\frac{\epsilon}2)$ right?

Comment: @gbox No, it should be that $||y-x|| < \frac \epsilon 2$. You can see that if $y$ is close to $x$, and if $x$ is far from $a$, then $y$ is going to be far from $a$, right? So I chose $y$ close enough ($\frac \epsilon 2$) to $x$ so that it would be far enough (greater than $r$) from $a$.