# How can I prove a closed ball is closed on metric topology?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, set-valued-analysis

Let $(X,\tau _d)$ is metric topology. 
Show that $B_r[x]$ is closed

$X\setminus B_r[x]$ must be open set. It is open iff $X\setminus B_r[x]  \in  \tau _d$ iff $\forall y  \in  X\setminus B_r[x]  ,  \exists \epsilon >0  , B_\epsilon (y) \subseteq X\setminus B_r[x] $

Assume $ z \in B_\epsilon (y) $
$d(y,z) \lt \epsilon$ and we know $d(x,y) \gt r$ from $y \in X\setminus B_r[x]$

How can I show $d(x,z) \gt r$ from inequalities??

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661759/a-closed-ball-in-a-metric-space-is-a-closed-set?rq=1

Comment: @A.Goodier I didn’t realise that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let K be the closed ball about a of radius r.
f(x) = d(a,x) is continuous.  I = [0,r] is closed.
Thus $K = f^{-1}(I)$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you. I d never think using a mapping