# Want to know if closed ball is closed set is equivalent to following theorem

Tags: real-analysis, advice

Ref: [A closed ball in a metric space is a closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661759/748810)

Is the question equivalent to this theorem:
A subset of a metric space is closed iff its complement is opened

I think they are pretty close. The theorem I quote mentions balls 
to prove.

I thought I might have to do more stuff to use this theorem

Comment: That's the definition of a closed set in a topology. So, the statement you presented is equivalent to: open balls generate the topology of a metric space.

Comment: So I can quote the theorem